# Don't generate TODO eclipse when i create new content

Tags: java, eclipse, generator, todo

I want Eclipse not to automatically generate some //TODO stuffs like this for example :

```
@Override
public String getPassword() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

I want to desactivate this feature in Eclipse...

Can somebody know how to deal with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can remove by exploring below path in your eclipse.

Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates.

In the code tree you have the templates. Select for example Code → Method Body and press **“Edit”** to edit this template and to remove the todo comment.

Comment: Note that Preferences are not in the 'Window' menu on macOS they are in the 'Eclipse' menu

Answer (score 2):

These are set by the Code Templates in the Preferences - Java > Code Style > Code Templates.

Look a the 'Method body', 'Constructor body', ... templates in the 'Code' section